# How to create the character Д for math mode?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, unicode, math-operators

In my research I'm using results of the paper [Vinogradov A. M., - The logic algebra for the theory of linear differential operators, - Soviet Math. Dokl., 13 (1972), 1058-1062](http://diffiety.ac.ru/djvu/logic_algebra.djvu). The paper uses the character looking like Д (Unicode hex U+0414) to refer to a specific operator:
[image: Д]

What I want is to write something like
`\newcommand\DD{\unicodesymbol{U+0414}}`
(which obviously doesn't work) and use `\DD` to refer to this symbol in math mode.
I've also found, that

```
\usepackage[OT2, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian, english]{babel}
\newcommand\DD{ {\operatorname{\textrm{\foreignlanguage{russian}{D}}}} }
```

seems to work, but I'm not sure, if this is a good way to define this symbol (e.g. if it doesn't break anything).

So, what is the best way to do that?

P.S. I tried to use [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-alphabet), and didn't find anything like Д. I also looked at [Comprehensive LaTeX symbols](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) and [AMS LaTeX Short Math Guide](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf), and the most close equivalend I've found is `\symrook` from `skak` package, which is still different.

**Update:** as was suggested in a [comment below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120935/how-to-create-the-character-for-math-mode?noredirect=1#comment269878_120935) by [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina) I now use

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[OT2, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian, english]{babel}
\DeclareMathOperator\DD{\textrm{\foreignlanguage{russian}{D}}}
```

Comment: What about the `\cyrd` command?

Comment: I'd use `\DeclareMathOperator` from `amsmath` (the starred version if "limits" are required). In the preamble: `\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\DD}{\textrm{\foreignlanguage{russian}{D}}}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This variant of `\DD`

- uses the `cm-super` fonts for the Cyrillic glyph (the fonts are available s Type 1 fonts and avoid bitmap fonts),
- supports `\boldsymbol` or `\mathversion{bold}`,
- is resizable,
- does not need package `babel`,
- only requires a font encoding that provides `\CYRD` (e.g. `T2A`).

Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\math@version@bold}{bold}
\DeclareMathOperator\DD{% or \DeclareMathOperator*\DD
  \textrm{%
    \usefont{T2A}{cmr}{\ifx\math@version\math@version@bold bx\else m\fi}{n}%
    \CYRD
  }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[\DD^{\DD^{\DD}} = \boldsymbol{\DD^{\DD^{\DD}}}\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]